# Out of Bounds exception with FileStream.BeginRead()

Tags: c#, filestream

So I building a small app to open and monitor a file for changes and display them a windows form.

I am having a issue however whenever a file is updated, it works fine when I first load the file however.

This is the segment of code I am using, it tells me that the:

```
Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of   elements from index to
the end of the source collection.
```

I am not sure what exactly is wrong with this logic as it should work fine. The m_lastFilePosition is set to 0 on the first load, and it is create a byte array of the expected size.

```
m_readingFile = true;
FileStream l_stream = new FileStream(m_fileToWatch, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
FileInfo l_info = new FileInfo(m_fileToWatch);
buffer = new byte[l_info.Length-m_lastFilePosition];

l_stream.BeginRead(buffer,
    (int)m_lastFilePosition,
    (int)(l_info.Length - m_lastFilePosition),
    new AsyncCallback(FileReadCallback),
    l_stream);
```

Has anyone encounters this before?

Comment: Your code is wrong.  Either the array must be l_info.Length or the 2nd argument to BeginRead must be 0 to avoid this exception.

Comment: That makes no sense, because the second param is an int offset and the third is a int numBytes. unless I need to seek, then read?

Comment: Alright so apparently I need to seek, then read, I will answer my own question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I owe part of this to Hans Passant as he helped point me in the right direction.

basically I changed the previously posted code to l_stream.Seek(m_lastFilePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin); then changed the offset to 0 and this solved my problem.

That was it, for solving it.

```
        m_readingFile = true;
        l_stream = new FileStream(m_fileToWatch, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        FileInfo l_info = new FileInfo(m_fileToWatch);

        if (m_lastFilePosition < l_info.Length)
        {

            buffer = new byte[l_info.Length - m_lastFilePosition];

            l_stream.Seek(m_lastFilePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            IAsyncResult result = l_stream.BeginRead(buffer,
                0,
                (int)(l_info.Length - m_lastFilePosition),
                new AsyncCallback(FileReadCallback),
                l_stream);
        }
    }
```